# How can I use grunt-uncss with an AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

My AngularJS application is composed by two urls:

- `http://myapp/#/foo`
- `http://myapp/#/bar`

This is the simplified index.html file:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

In addition to containing the application logic, the `script.js` file also contains the html templates that are loaded via [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service.

With the `http://myapp/#/foo` url, the **foo** html template is inserted in the `<div ui-view></div>` element. In the same way, with the `http://myapp/#/bar` url, the **bar** html template is inserted in `<div ui-view></div>`.

What I want to do is to use the [grunt-uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) task to reduce the `style.css` size.

My first attempt was:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {  
    files: {
      'style.css': [ 'index.html' ]
    }
}
```

The `style.css` file was reduced, but it did not included the styles required by the **foo** and **bar** pages.

My second attempt was using the [deprecated `urls` parameter](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#options) to be loaded with PhantomJS:

```
uncss: {
  options: {
    urls; [ 'http://myapp/#/foo', 'http://myapp/#/bar' ]
  },
  dist: {  
    files: {
      'style.css': [ 'index.html' ]
    }
}
```

Again, the `style.css` file was reduced, but it did not included the styles required by the **foo** and **bar** pages.

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Does grunt-uncss only work with static content?

Thanks in advance,

Bernardo Pacheco

Comment: do /foo and /bar each have their own stylesheets? or is it all contained within style.css

Comment: @KevinB no, all styles are contained in the style.css file

Comment: I don't see any examples of this being used on an angular app with multiple routes that have css that isn't also being used on the front.I think the `urls:` option is going to be the only one that works, and that is only going to work if your angular app is in html5 mode.

Comment: Are your templates static files? could you just point to those static files in addition to index.html?

Comment: @KevinB I converted my angular app to html5 mode and tested with the `urls` parameter, but it did not worked. My templates contains simple templates, just some bootstrap classes, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Specify all your html files, including views:

```
uncss: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            ignore: ['.ng-move', '.ng-enter', '.ng-leave', '.created_by_jQuery']
        },
        files: {
            'style.css': [ 'index.html', 'views/foo.html', 'views/bar.html' ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can specify more than one file of html, so you should include all your view files (in this case foo.html and bar.html). Also, use ignore option to add classes that are loaded at runtime (do not already exist in html files), i.e. created by jQuery, or ngAnimate if you are using one.

There are more options, for example you can customize which media queries should be left after uncssing, please refer to the documentation provided by authors - https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss.

Comment: I have the similar problem, I configured ignore option but uncss not ingore multiple selector clases like .firs.second and I have thousand of selectors like this in my css file

Comment: Same here, I tried using both options.urls and passing in array of urls into files, but neither seem to actually be seeing a rendered version of the app because it is cutting out all nested/specific styles of directive templates that are added at runtime. I would love to see an example of this working on a large angular app that has alot of directives.

Comment: Doesn't this project evaluate the javascript for injected classes?

Answer (score 0):

*shameless plug*

You can refer to my example repo on github. There it has a full example of a simple todo app running angular, bower, and grunt-uncss.

Edit: Sorry about that thought I had added the link

https://github.com/JeremyCarlsten/grunt-uncss-angular-example

The basic configuration would be to add the below code to your gruntfile

```js
uncss: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'path/to/where/you/want/cleaned.css': ['path/to/index.html'] // the index html could be a list of html files that all include css files
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This answer is not incredibly useful in its current form, but if you could add a link to your repo and a relevant code snippet showing how it could be used to solve the problem as posed by the asker, this could be made into a viable answer.